# How to use the same port for React Js and Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Actually, I am looking to create the contact form in the website using reactjs and nodejs. I have created the form using the React and for the backend, I have to connect the node js so that I can receive the email. But it is not happening
Both React and Node should run on the same port. I have given a proxy as "http://localhost:3000" in the package.json but still, it's not working.

**I have given both the react js and node js code. Please help me to solve this error.**

### React JS Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class formSection extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    subject: "",
    comment: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

 async handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {name, email, subject, comment} = this.state

    const contact = await axios.post('/api/contact', {

        name,
        email,
        subject,
        comment

    })

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <section
        className="wow fadeIn big-section"
        id="section-down"
        style={{ visibility: true }}
      >
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row equalize sm-equalize-auto">
            <div
              className="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 sm-margin-30px-bottom wow fadeInLeft"
              style={{ visibility: true, height: 597 }}
            >
              <div className="padding-fifteen-all bg-light-gray border-radius-6 md-padding-seven-all xs-padding-30px-all height-100">
                <span className="text-extra-dark-gray alt-font text-large font-weight-600 margin-25px-bottom display-block">
                  Ready to get started?
                </span>
                <form id="contact-form" onSubmit={e=>this.handleSubmit(e)} method="POST">
                  <div>
                    <div
                      id="success-contact-form"
                      className="no-margin-lr"
                      style={{ display: true }}
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      id="name"
                      value={this.state.name}
                      placeholder="Name*"
                      className="border-radius-4  medium-input"
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="email"
                      value={this.state.email}
                      id="email"
                      placeholder="E-mail*"
                      className="border-radius-4  medium-input"
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="subject"
                      id="subject"
                      value={this.state.subject}
                      placeholder="Subject"
                      className="border-radius-4  medium-input"
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <textarea
                      name="comment"
                      id="comment"
                      value={this.state.comment}
                      placeholder="Your Message"
                      rows="5"
                      className="border-radius-4  medium-textarea"
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <button
                      id="contact-us-button"
                      type="submit"
                      className="btn btn-small border-radius-4 btn-dark-gray"

                    >
                      send message
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              className="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 last-paragraph-no-margin wow fadeInRight"
              style={{ visibility: true, height: 597 }}
            >
              <div className="padding-ten-all bg-light-gray border-radius-6 md-padding-seven-all xs-padding-30px-all height-100 sm-text-center">
                <img
                  src="images/about-img1.jpg"
                  alt=""
                  className="border-radius-6 margin-35px-bottom xs-margin-30px-bottom"
                  data-no-retina=""
                />
                <span className="text-large font-weight-600 alt-font text-extra-dark-gray margin-5px-bottom display-block">
                  Let's plan for a new project?
                </span>
                <p>
                  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                  typesetting industry, Lorem Ipsum has been the standard dummy
                  text.
                </p>
                <a
                  href="about-us-modern.html"
                  className="btn btn-dark-gray btn-small text-extra-small border-radius-4 margin-25px-top"
                >
                  About Company
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

### Node JS Code

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.post('/api/contact', (req, res) => {

console.log(req.body);

});




const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {

    console.log(`server listening in port ${PORT}`);

})
```

Comment: want you  run react and node on equal port?

Comment: Yeah on Port 3000! I tried but not working. Could you please help?

Comment: React doesn't run on its own port.  It runs on Node, which runs on port 3000.  It's not clear what your problem is.  In what way is it "not working"?  Where are you injecting React into your index page?

Comment: you can do this JUST when use one nodejs server for react SSR and API sever. this is mean you can not use tools like create-react-app. are you use tools or pure react?

Comment: @mihai Created the form using React(i.e)Front End. Now have to send email using node js server. If I start the node server, the front end is not working. Please check the code above.

Comment: @jmorgolisvt Getting error as "Cannot GET /" while running the node server

Comment: @Keith Brewster yeah it's working but needs to run with react js

Answer (score 7):

You can't achieve this with the approach you are following.

**why?**

you are trying to run two different servers at a single port (node server and webpackdev server)

**Any alternative?**

yes, as per your requirement you don't need a separate server for the frontend, you can serve it as static files.

**How?**

1. build your application (for create-react-app `npm run build`)
2. copy all the contents of `build` folder to a new folder (say `public`) in your express application.
3. now add below in your node js code (to serve static files):

   `app.use('/', express.static('./public'));`

**and now visit `http://localhost:3000`**

Comment: any downside for this? pros and cons? it works for me. It is safe in production?

Comment: i think in production you need to specify in package.json to build the `react-app` than copy the content from build to `public` folder,maybe using github action you can achieve this

Comment: How to handle reshresh case on this. Say I have an endpoint /schema and I typed this in browser and refresh. But this endpoint will hit back end (node) and error will be thrown as Cannot GET /schema. How to redirect to public folder if the endpoint is not present in API.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're using create-react-app, and you've added proxy configuration to package.json.

Create-react-app is started on 3000 port, so your express server should start on any other port (NOT 3000), then you change the proxy configuration to that port.

I.e. const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
Than change frontend package.json proxy configuration like "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"

Notice, that this should be used for development only. For production: build the bundle, and use express to serve static contents from build folder.

Comment: I did accordingly but getting an error as "Cannot GET /"

Comment: @Ameen check the log of the server process. does it states "server listening in port 5000"? I'm asking, since I've just made all of these steps, and everything works fine.

Comment: @Ameen, wait, how are you checking that?

Comment: yeah got the same status message as "server listening in port 5000". No error in that

Comment: Using visual studio code editor, there it shows the status and using nodemon as well to restart the server

Comment: @Ameen I mean how you get "Cannot GET /"?
Navigate to http://localhost:3000 and hit submit, then check you vscode console

Comment: Same status "server listening in port 3000"

Comment: @Ameen, backend should be started on 5000, and the logs should state "server listening on port 5000", while the frontend should be started on 3000 (using yarn or npm start). Then you navigate to localhost:3000 and hit submit button, after that the request body should appear in backend console

Answer (score 3):

if you use tools like `create-react-app` answer is **'can not do this'**, because you cannot edit `nodejs` server and in other side in production mode, `create-react-app` build project and have not any `nodejs` server in production.

but when you develop react as pure and SSR then you can access to nodejs server and can do this.

**see this for react SSR:**

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/demystifying-reacts-server-side-render-de335d408fe4

Comment: Someone marked a question I posted as possible duplicate. Not sure if it applies, since my goal would be to run 2 scripts (separate files) in one port. Is that possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62155391/can-i-run-node-and-react-ssr-in-the-same-port

Answer (score 1):

**Solution if you use webpack/dev-server**

`package.json` file:

`"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",`

If you use dev-sever with webpack, then in `webpack.cofing.js` add this:

```
    proxy: {
        '/api': "http://localhost:5000",
    },
```

`backend.js` file:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
});

server.listen({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5000,
});
```

When you open site type: `localhost:8080` (or which is default for you), and then when you want to open your `node.js` server just add `/api` in your url it should look like this: `localhost:8080/api`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution How to start react and nodejs app on the same port.
please open git link
https://github.com/chandrakant1990/react-node-express-app-on-same-port

Take a clone of this repo.
In Client forlder just fire command
npm install
then start the app
sh start.sh

Your app will be started on localhost:3000

For Client side changes You need not to restart the app again.
For server side changes please restart the app.

For more details you can see video
https://youtu.be/AiEC2_8mIIY

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is best to achieve using the same port is to use server-side rendering. you can learn more about this here

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/demystifying-reacts-server-side-render-de335d408fe4/